# JPA oneToMany with columns having a different database type

Tags: jpa

I have 2 tables and a bidirectional oneToMany relationship to specify between the 2.
My problem is that the column of the parent table and the column of the child table have not the same database type (Varchar and Number). How to make JPA 2 (EclipseLink 2.3.1) "join" those 2 tables with columns having a different type ?

Thanks !

fred

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Why don't you fix your schema?

Comment: because I am not allowed to ! :-( I know it looks dirty ...